# Overwrite the invalid token message for password reset

Tags: php, laravel

How can you overwrite the token message 'This password reset token is invalid.'

I've tried adding this into my ResetPasswordController but it still displays the default token message.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        return config('user.redirect', route('user.dashboard'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'This password reset token is invalid. <a href="' . route('password.request') . '">Request a new password</a>'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }
}
```

I need to add a URL instead of just changing the text. [Overwrite Error text for 'The password reset token is invalid' Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067096/overwrite-error-text-for-the-password-reset-token-is-invalid-laravel)

I've discovered it's the $this->broker()->reset() which actually validates the token. Is the only way to overwrite the token message by fully overwrite this method?

```
/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `sendResetFailedResponse` method to change the message. The `$response` is passed to that method which is the translation key for that message which is `passwords.token` (See `resources/lang/en/passwords.php`).

```php
/**
 * Get the response for a failed password reset.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ["Your custom error message here"],
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => "Your custom error message here"]);
}
```